# XML Serialization and how it handles writing out to a file

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I have searched far and wide and have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

I have a typical situation where a process is gradually eating up memory.  The process eventually throws an OutofMemory Exception.  This problem has been dealt with in the past by just building a special machine that has greater memory.

This process bombs on only one of our clients which has around 450,000 records.  We iterate through the collection of accounts and build a class object that is then passed into the xml serializer.  This object has several properties and methods that would not all be populated at the same time.  These objects are populated based on the information in each account record.

I've checked on the way we call the contructor for the XML Serializer and it is in the format that would store the xml assembly and not create new ones each time.  So, I do not believe there is a memory leak due to the creation of the dynamic assemblies.

How we call the serializer: Dim k1Serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ClassObject))

My questions are:

When serializing a large object, does the serializer look at every possible serializable object or just the ones that are populated by your object?

Could the serialization of this large class object be causing an issue?

I noticed when we pass in the serialized object, it's not automatically written out to the file specified.  It takes a few seconds to, I guess, serialize the object and then write it out.  Could the fact that we are iterating over so many records, so quickly, that the serializer is not having enough time to write out to the file and then release the memory?

I'm really at my wits end and any help would be appreciated.  Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks

Comment: can you show more actual code, illustrating how you call the serializer, and what are you serializing *into*.

Answer (score 0):

Loading 450,000 records in to the memory at the same time just for writing it out to an XML file does not look to be a good idea to me. I would suggest that you re-architect the functionality by using XMLWriter instead of XML Serializer, that way the whole set of information need not be kept in the memory at the same time.

Comment: We load the 450,000 records to an array of objects and then loop through those objects populating them with the necessary data and then passing each object into the XML Serializer.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear in the first post.

Answer (score -1):

Consider looking into the [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx).  You can *manually* write out the XML data for your data, without resorting to the blackbox that is the XmlSerializer.

A simple example for iterating through a list of items, and writing them out to an XML file:

```
var settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent= true
};    
string myXmlNamespace = "urn:myXmlNamespace";
using (var fileStream = 
    new FileStream("MyFile.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
  using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, settings)) 
  {
    w.WriteStartElement("root", myXmlNamespace);
    for (var elt in myCollection) 
    {
      w.WriteStartElement("elt",myXmlNamespace);
      w.WriteElementString("prop1",myXmlNamespace,elt.Property1); 
      w.WriteElementString("prop2",myXmlNamespace,elt.Property2);
      w.WriteEndElement();
    }
  }
}
```

You'd have to do the converse for "de-serializing".  Open a filestream then use an XmlTextReader() to read the XML, and instantiate elements to add to your collection.

Comment: -1 no, use `XmlWriter.Create`. `XmlTextWriter` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Comment: ah, ok good point. I remember that now. In my defense, the doc page for XmlTextWriter still shows examples using the constructor.

Comment: We use an XmlWriter to pass into the XML Serializer.  We use the serializer because we have to populate many objects and I feel that rewriting the whole process to use the XmlWriter would not be a great solution as of now.  We plan on doing some rewriting of our process later in the future.  Is using the XML Serializer a poor choice to begin with.  By using the serializer I don't have to worry about writing out startelement, endelement, etc each time.

Comment: ps, John, your downvote because of a smaller point on the example code seems pretty harsh.

Comment: to answer your question "is using XmlSerializer a poor choice to begin with?" - *maybe*. With 450,000 records, I'd probably look first to a real database, instead of an XML format. My answer above, the suggestion to use XmlWriter directly, is based on the assumption that you are wedded to an XML format. In that case, I'm suggesting you use a lower-level API to write the XML yourself, so as to possibly avoid the out-of-memory condition. Just curious - how do you create the XmlWriter you use *now*? Is it backed by a FileStream?

Comment: The XML Writer that we use now using a filename that we pass in.  It's pretty much like this: XmlWriter.Create("path to file", writterSettings)                                                                                                                         We then use that as a baswriter and pass it into another writer that I believe that we created called: XmlNoNamespaceWriter.  That was done so that the XMLWriter didn't create a namespace.